# 300ms delay loading Tailwind into Gatsby site

Tags: gatsby, tailwind-css

Whenever I hit the refresh button, it takes about 300ms before the styling is working.
I can't see what I should be missing, since I have followed a lot of guides, about setting up tailwind in Gatsby.

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  purge: ["./src/**/*.js", "./src/**/*.jsx"],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
    fontFamily: {
      display: ["Source Sans Pro"],
      body: ["Source Sans Pro"],
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

```
// postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

```
// gatsby-config.js
...
plugins: ['gatsby-plugin-postcss'],
```

```
// gatsby-browser.js
import "./src/styles/global.css";
```

```
// src/styles/global.css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try something like this:

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  purge: ["./src/**/*.js", "./src/**/*.jsx"],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
    fontFamily: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: ['gatsby-plugin-postcss'],
};
```

Among installing and configuring [`gatsby-plugin-postcss`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-postcss/), I would also try removing the `fontFamily` object, at least only for testing purpose, since one of the reasons when dealing with **F**lash **O**f **U**ninstyled **C**ontent (FOUC) is because of the fonts, if they are not set in `display: swap`, they block may block the style rendering until they are fully loaded.

If the issue is fixed by removing the fonts plus `gatsby-plugin-postcss`, you can try adding the fonts in a different way.

Comment: Thanks for trying! But sadly no effect :(

Comment: Does it happen also in `gatsby build`?

Comment: It is now fixed. I ran into this issue https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/27644 running gatsby serve, which made me update gatsby to latest - which solved the problem :)

Comment: That's why I was thinking. The other solution was to upgrade the key packages. Tailwind behaves differently between develop and build modes due to its inherited configuration. If the issue has been solved please consider accepting/upvoting the answer to close the issue